# Printing Struct that is within linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have 2 structs, one with array of name and surname, and other which is linked list. Each node having the struct with name and surname inside it.

```
typedef struct name {
  char given_name[200];
  char surname[200];
} Name;

typedef struct list {
    long id_number;
    Name *name;
    struct list *next;
} List;

void main() {
     list *head = NULL;
     add_to_list(&head);
     print_list(&head);
}

void add_to_list(List **head) {
    List *tmp_new;
    List *prev;
    tmp_new = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    (tmp_new->name) = malloc(sizeof(Name));
    
    strcpy((tmp_new->name->given_name), "John");
    strcpy((tmo_new->name->surname), "Blake");
    tmp_new->id = atoi("654");
    
    tmp_new->next = NULL;
    
    /////////  <- next part is here because 
    /////////   i have it within while cycle
    /////////    and this is how i move to the next cell in linked list
    if ((*head) == NULL) {
       *head = tmp_new;
        prev = tmp_new;
    } else {
       prev->next= tmp_new;
       prev = tmp_new;
    }
    /////////// upcoming next iteration
    strcpy((tmp_new->name->given_name), "Tom");
    strcpy((tmo_new->name->names), "Jerry");
    tmp_new->id = atoi("4568");
}

void print_list(List **head) {
    List *tmp;
    tmp = *head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        printf("\n Name: %s", tmp->name->given_name);
        printf("\n Surname: %s", tmp->name->surname);
        printf("\n ID: %ld", tmp->id_number);
        printf("\n");
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

The loading or the print doesn't give me any errors. But the print gives me something weird.
**expected:**

```
Name: John
Surname: Blake
ID: 654

Name: Tom
Surname: Jerry
ID:4568
```

**what it gives:**

```
Name: Tom
Surname: Jerry
ID: 654

Name: Tom
Surname: Jerry
ID:4568
```

so it seems that even though it goes trough the linked list, it seems that the struct name is by itself is not within the cell of the list. How should it be done so it is within?

Comment: Your basic problem is that you do not allocate separate `Name` structures for John Blake and Tom Jerry, so when you copy Tom Jerry's data into the structure, you overwrite John Blake's information.  You need to restructure your `add_to_list()` function so that it takes the list head, the forename, surname, and ID number, and returns a pointer to the new head of the list (or it takes a pointer to the head pointer and updates that).  You can then call it twice in the `main()` function.  And the function will allocate a new name each time it is called.

Comment: You're not doing anything useful with `prev`. At a first glance the problem is with your `add_to_list`. Look there! The print is simple, ergo less possible to get it wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you do not allocate separate `Name` structures for John Blake and Tom Jerry, so when you copy Tom Jerry's data into the structure, you overwrite John Blake's information. It's not even clear to me that you have two `List` structures allocated — I've not tested your code with Valgrind or equivalent, but I think you're seriously abusing memory.

You need to restructure your `add_to_list()` function so that it only adds one person — and that person should be identified by the arguments to the function.  It should take the list head, the forename, surname, and ID number, and should return a pointer to the new head of the list (or it should take a pointer to the head pointer and update that). You should then call it twice in the `main()` function. The function will allocate a new name and a list item each time it is called.  A function should do one job.

```
List *add_to_list(List *head, const char *forename, const char *surname, int id);
```

or (but less sensible):

```
void add_to_list(List **p_head, const char *forename, const char *surname, int id);
```

It's a little silly to use `tmp_new->id = atoi("4568");` rather than `tmp_new->id = 4568;`, but that will cease to be a problem when you rewrite the function as proposed.